# Etymology of "stillen" and relation to other languages

Tags: etymology, verb, vocabulary

Looking on the [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=breastfeed&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on), the verb *stillen* means to breastfeed.

The English verb contains the word *breast*. Something similar happens in Italian (*allattare*, which contains *latte*-milk).

What is the etymology of *stillen*? Does it have anything to do with the English word *[still](http://etymonline.com/?term=still)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. The verb *["stillen"](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=stillen)* indeed originates from the same stem with the English and Old English *["to still"](http://etymonline.com/?term=still)*. Both are also found in Old Saxonian (stilli) and West Germanic (stellja-).

Originally it only had the meaning of *to calm, to satisfy*. In Middle High German only this meaning shifted towards *to allay hunger or thirst*, and to nures a child in the 16th Century. Since then it is used for a mother (breast) feeding her child.

From [Grimm's Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS47173) we find the following very early examples of this usage:

> "mater lactat seuget oder stillet das kind" *Steph. Riccius Terent. com. Andria (1586) 382*; "und die mütter also auszgesogen werden, dasz sie nicht mehr stillen können" *J. Ruoff hebammenbuch (1580) 152*; "Erassmus ... hatte eine seugamme bestellet, das kind zu stillen" *Grimmelshausen 2*

It was indeed used in the meaning of to calm down the otherwise crying child with a considerable overlap with the other meaning of to allay one's thirst.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is related to *still*, originally meaning *make silent*, *calm down* etc. See the [entry in Deutsches Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=stillen) (section 2c, far down in the article).

There are alternative expressions, such as *(einem Kind) die Brust geben*.

Answer (score 4):

I use *stillen* only in these situations:

- **breastfeed**

> Die Mutter stillt ihr Baby.

- **to allay so.'s (thirst/hunger)**

> Ich stille meinen Durst und Hunger, indem ich etwas trinke und etwas
>   esse.

- **to satisfy curiosity**

> Ich konnte meine Neugierde stillen, indem ich das Geschenk endlich auspackte.

- **to soothe a pain**

> Die Tabletten halfen, den Schmerz zu stillen.

---

Rarely I hear:

- **to stop a bleed / to staunch a wound**

> Der Arzt konnte die Blutung der Wunde stillen

(in my opinion "Der Arzt konnte die Blutung **stoppen**" would be better, but stillen in this case is also correct I think)

---

**Update:**

Sorry, while thinking too much about the examples, I forgot about to answer to the etymology of stillen:

Beside some sources telling you it's coming from *still sein* (being silent), it *"feels"* for me that's just one possible part. When thinking further, it has also a kind of relationship to the words *"beruhigen"* and *"mäßigen" (to moderate)* and to the phrase *"wieder im Einklang sein mit etwas" (to be again in line with sth., to harmonize, to resonate)*

Comment: Always interesting to hear about the connotations that people associate with individual words. It gives one a chance to compare these to one's own mind-map. Nonetheless, connotations are not etymology; just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Bei einer Blutung ist _still legen_ imo genau so passend wie _stoppen_.